# Why jquery work in Chrome but not on Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

It works fine in *`Chrome`* but when I open this code in *`Safari`* calendar not show properly. If I click on today button then calendar display properly.

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('.fc-basicWeek-button').click();
});
```

It is also not working on *`IE`*.

I want that calendar will display without clicking the today button.
So I tried this code so button will automatically click but this code is work fine on *`Chrome`* but not on *`Safari`* or *`IE`*.

Comment: Where you put this code? he problem might be the code is loaded before the calendar component is rendered. For best results add script tag to end of body tag. Also try to add debugger statement and inspect the dom see if indeed this is the problem.

Comment: sir it work fine on chrome ...... but when i run code on safari jquery not work fine also not showing any error

Comment: see my comment on smit's answer. this is the most  probable cause

Comment: Have you loaded the latest jquery in the head area. If make sure if your using codeigniter that base_url is set in config.php

Comment: user4419336 can you send me the link for latest jquery file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.fc-basicWeek-button').trigger("click");

});
```

You need to `trigger` click event.

Comment: window.onload=show_me();
 
  
  function show_me(){
  
      jQuery(function(){
                   jQuery('.fc-basicWeek-button').trigger("click");

            });
 
   
 }

Comment: try with: `window.onload=show_me`  (without the parens ())

Comment: according to me jquery is not loading in safari can you please tell me the reason of this

Comment: You should use `$(document).ready` instead on `window.onload` beacuse maybe your button is not even rendered when you try to trigger the click action

Comment: still same issue showing no error but on safari it did not show proper result :'(

Comment: without clicking on today button it will not show the calendar